# Select an element from dynamicaly appended childs

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a div which it's content updates by receiving new data from ajax. I remove old content and append new data to the div. The problem is when I cant select a child that has appended to div.

Here's my code:

```
<div id="page-container" style="width: 55px;"> //div I want to update contents
     <div class="page-div">1</div> // appended childs
     <div class="page-div">2</div>
</div>
```

these lines doesn't work:

```
$("#page-container:nth-child(2)")
$("#page-container").eq(1)
```

Do you guys know what's the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need

```
$("#page-container > :nth-child(2)")
```

or

```
$("#page-container > :eq(1)")
$("#page-container").children(':eq(1)')
$("#page-container").children().eq(1)
```

Note: You need to execute these selectors only after the children are appended

`#page-container:nth-child(2)` looks for an element with id `page-container` which is the second child of its parent

`$("#page-container").eq(1)` looks for an element with id `page-container` which is at index 1 which will never be there because the id selector will always return 1 element